# wxTaskBarIcon Right Click event not working

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

First time I try to use this in a wxWidget program, I don't know what i'm missing but when I right click on my icon, nothing happens. 
I tried to begin an event table but `BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(wxTaskBarIconBase, wxTaskBarIcon)` does not compile, it's probably not the good class to put in, but I really dont know what to put.

The icone is well displayed and everything compiles, but nothing happens in the RightClickDown event..

here's my code(not full just the needed part, same for .h)

.cpp :

```
#include <wx/taskbar.h>
#include<wx/menu.h>

wxTaskBarIcon* mataskBarIcon = new wxTaskBarIcon();
wxMenu* monMenu = new wxMenu(wxString::FromUTF8("Imthemenu"));
wxIcon icon;

icon.LoadFile(wxString::FromUTF8("myicone.gif"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_GIF);
mataskBarIcon->SetIcon(icon, wxString::FromUTF8("ImtheIcone"));


void wxTaskBarIconBase::OnRightButtonDown(wxTaskBarIconEvent& event)
{
     printf("test\n");
    mataskBarIcon->CreatePopupMenu();
    mataskBarIcon->PopupMenu(monMenu);

}
```

wx/taskbar.h :

```
class WXDLLIMPEXP_ADV wxTaskBarIconBase : public wxEvtHandler
{
public:
    wxTaskBarIconBase() { }

    // Operations:
    virtual bool SetIcon(const wxIcon& icon,
                         const wxString& tooltip = wxEmptyString) = 0;
    virtual bool RemoveIcon() = 0;
    virtual bool PopupMenu(wxMenu *menu) = 0;


protected:
    // creates menu to be displayed when user clicks on the icon
    virtual wxMenu *CreatePopupMenu() { return NULL; }

private:
    // default events handling, calls CreatePopupMenu:
    void OnRightButtonDown(wxTaskBarIconEvent& event);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
    DECLARE_NO_COPY_CLASS(wxTaskBarIconBase)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you changing `wxTaskBarIconBase` itself? This doesn't make any sense, it's a library class, you should inherit from it and override its virtual `CreatePopupMenu()` method instead of changing it.

Besides, your event handler is not connected to anything at all, at least in the code you show, so it's hardly surprising it is never called.

But this is not how you're supposed to use this class anyhow. If all your efforts to do it failed, perhaps it's time to have a look at [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_task_bar_icon.html)? It clearly mentions overriding `CreatePopupMenu()`. And if it's still not detailed enough, have a look at the [taskbar sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/master/samples/taskbar/tbtest.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

First, you SHOULD NOT change wxTaskBarIconBase code. Either inherit from it or create a custom wxEvtHandler to deal with the event.

Second, I can not really help with the `DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE`. The syntax is heavy and it does not allow for dynamic event handling. In my opinion you should avoid it. My recommendation is to use `Connect`. Here's and example:

```
class TaskBarHandler : 
  public ::wxEvtHandler
{
public:
  void OnIconEvent(wxEvent& the_event)
  {
    wxEventType const type = the_event.GetEventType();
    if (type == wxEVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_UP)
    {
      // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
  }
};

void CreateBar()
{
  wxTaskBarIcon* bar = new wxTaskBarIcon();
  TaskBarHandler* handler = new TaskBarHandler();
  handler->Connect(
    wxID_ANY, 
    wxEVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_UP,
    (wxObjectEventFunction) (&TaskBarHandler::OnIconEvent ),
    (wxObject*)NULL, 
    handler);
  // later
  delete handler;
}
```

Comment: Well I understand this example, i tried it, it compiles, but nothing happens when i right click on the icone. I just did several printf to test and I reach the Connect() in CreateBar() when my program starts. But I cant reach the OnIconEvent(), how can I link my TaskBarIcon to the event?   i'm very lost in the event logic

Comment: Have you tried using `wxEVT_COMMAND_RIGHT_CLICK` instead of `wxEVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_UP`

Comment: This is not the problem....  the event is not linked to the icone... how can the program know the event is only for the icon area?  it's not defined at all... I don't know how to do that, it's not about the frame but about the system tray